# How to restrict a user to enter Integer value using Annotations?

Tags: java, regex, spring, validation, annotations

I am trying some field validations using annotations like `@Regexp, @Notnull,@NotBlank etc`. I use a message. Property file to display my error messages like

```
MerchantView.merchantPosId[not.blank]=Please enter merchant pos id's
MerchantView.merchantPosId[regexp]=Please enter merchant pos id's in comma separated numbers
MerchantView.merchantPosId[length]=Please do not enter more than 100 Characters.
MerchantView.accountNumber[not.null]=Please enter merchant account number.
```

I am able to do all the field validation with a string field or when a field is empty(even for long and integer fields).

But i am unable to populate any custom message for my Integer or Long field.What kind of annotations do i need to use.Thanks

Comment: What is it you want to validate on those fields? Please expand your question.

Comment: I want to enter Long values in my field.I know of a trick of using String to get values and then later using Integer to store.But i want to enter long or integer values from a jsp page and save as it is in database.

Comment: I must be missing something. Assuming you use Spring MVC that does the type-conversion from String <-> Long/Integer. Not something you can do/influence with validation. Hence my initial question what do you want to validate on those field.

Comment: OK.I need to validate if the user has entered a number value or not with help of annotations.On failure, a error message should be given.

Comment: That cannot be done with an annotation on an Integer or Long typed field. That will only work on a String field and check with an expression (for instance) that it is numeric. The `Pattern` annotation can be used for that. Or the `Digits` annotation.

Comment: I tried using  type="number" in my jsp page and in our Dao class @Type="integer"...but it is not working as well.Is there any other way apart form retrieving data in string and then later storing it as my desired format which is Long ?